# HighCharts API pie chart CSS how to select drilldown labels

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, highcharts

I have made a pie chart using highcharts and making a chart with the following options

```
chart: {
          type: 'pie',
       },
```

and I added the below options to change the width of the text which forces each word to be on a different line

```
plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              format: '{point.name} {point.y}',
              style: {
                width: 50,
                fontSize: '20px',
              },
             }
            }
```

I try to change the color of the label by adding a color property to the style, but it wont change the color. How would I change the color, as well as the text underline?

This is the label that I am talking about that is on my highcharts pie chart,

[image: pie chart label]

Thank you, also a bonus question would be, is there a way that I could make a giant white circle in the middle of the pie chart? sort of like making a hole in a donut?

Answer (score 0):

The label color is configured by [`dataLabels.color`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.color):

```js
plotOptions: {
  pie: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      color: 'green', 
    }
  }
}
```

[demo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/5910ajwu/)

or [`dataLabels.style.color`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.CSSObject#color):

```
plotOptions: {
  pie: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      style: {
        color: 'green', 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/2abur5yh/)

For a [drilldown pie chart](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-drilldown), the label color is configured by `plotOptions.series.dataLabels.color` and `series.data[].dataLabels.color` (where each data point can have its own color config):

```js
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: '{point.name}: {point.y:.1f}%',
      color: 'green', 
    }
  }
},

series: [
  {
    name: "Browsers",
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [
      {
        name: "Chrome",
        y: 62.74,
        drilldown: "Chrome",
        dataLabels: {
          color: 'green', 
        }
      },
      {
        name: "Firefox",
        y: 10.57,
        drilldown: "Firefox",
        dataLabels: {
          color: 'green', 
        }
      },
      //...
    ]
  }
]
```

[demo 3](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/XWMNXmb?editors=1010)

[`drilldown.activeDataLabelStyle.color`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown.activeDataLabelStyle.color) can also be used:

```js
drilldown: {
  activeDataLabelStyle: {
    color: 'green' 
  },
}
```

[demo 4](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/poeNYPL?editors=1010)

Comment: the best solution I found actually was to use `activeDataLabelStyle` property in the drilldown options, thank you very much for all the help